# jQuery : How to access data within the <span> tag?

Tags: jquery

This is my jQuery code.

```
function hideawsbutton() {



            $("#aws-display-table tbody tr").each(function(index){


                parentdata = $.trim($(this).children('td:nth-child(7)').html());
                console.log('parentdata  ==> ' + parentdata);
                if( parentdata.length > 5 )
                    {
                        $(this).children('td:nth-child(8)').html('');    
                    }

            });
        }
```

The code checks for value in a specific column `td:nth-child(7)` and if it's length is less than 5, then sets the adjoining column's `td:nth-child(8)` html to null/empty.

I assumed that the table will always contain values but I have been told that the cell will have the data but embedded within a `<span>` tag as shown below.

This is my console log output as you can see the data is embedded in between the span tag.

```
parentdata  ==> <span id="j_id0:alphap-acc-details:aws-list-repeat:1:awsvar-parentdocname">15-02-2018-15:31:44PM_Presentation1.pptx</span>

parentdata  ==> <span id="j_id0:alphap-acc-details:aws-list-repeat:2:awsvar-parentdocname"></span>
```

Can someone tell me how I can access the data within the span tag ?

Comment: Just to be clear.  When you say *the data within the span tag* what are you referring to?

Comment: For the first console log output "15-02-2018-15:31:44PM_Presentation1.pptx" is the data. And for the second log there is no data. Do let me know if I am not clear..tx !

Comment: @Taplar : Do put this as answer. It helped !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(this).children('td:nth-child(7) span').html()
```

Or you can use text() like J.M. has in their answer.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

`$(this).children('td:nth-child(8)').html('');`

try

`$(this).children('td:nth-child(8)').children('span').text();`

hope it helps